# Support move to SD in Android when the project is 2.1

Tags: java, android

I have an application, its a 2.1 project. I'd like to add "Move to sd" option to my application. How should I do it? 
I must create a new project for android 2.2? If yes how can I make for keep the whole app maintainable and don't have two sepparated projects?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Just compile your project using the 2.2 SDK. Then you can use `installLocation` option in AndroidManifest.xml.

Answer (score 1):

What Nikolay said is correct.
To expand it :
In the project / Properties / Android, set the Android version to whatever >= 2.2.

Then in your manifest, set the minimum Android version you are supporting :
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7"/>

( I think Android 2.1 is 6 ).
And to enable relocation, still in the manifest :

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:installLocation="auto"
      package="com.XXX.APPLICATION_NAME"
      android:versionCode="XX"
      android:versionName="XX.XX.XX">

And that's it.
Just be careful not to use some functionality from Android 2.2 only, because it won't work anymore on a 2.1 device.